# Find method in another workbook not working as expected

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to `.find` cell address from a different workbook:

```
Dim ra As Range
With Workbooks("Input Nsales.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set ra = Cells.Find(What:="Basis", LookIn:=xlValues)
    If ra Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox ("Not found")
    Else
        MsgBox (ra.Address)
    End If
End With
```

My googling skills are not good enough, please help!

Edit: Wow thanks for quick answers! One more question, how do I get the column number from above found cell? e.g "2" for "B1"
This is what I tried but didn't work:

```
Dim BasisCol As Integer
Set BasisCol = ra.Column
```

Comment: Qualify your `Cells` reference by using `.Cells` instead - that's how it knows to use the `With` - Without that, it assumes `ActiveSheet`

Comment: To add on, missing the dot cause your code `Cells.Find...` to make VBA assume that you are referring to the `ActiveSheet` so your code effectively means `Set ra = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find(...`

Comment: Thanks for quick answers, please see new question edited..

Comment: `Integer` is not an object type so you just need `BasisCol = ra.Column`. Only for object variable you will need to use `Set`. Side-Note: There's pretty much no reason to use `Integer` type in VBA so I'll suggest you to change it to `Long`.@RaymondYu

Comment: Icic thx so much!

Comment: @RaymondYu Note: You will need to use `@[username]` to ping someone or else we will not receive any notification.